# Why am I seeing an NSUnknownKeyException when setting up a CIAdditionCompositing filter?

Tags: ios, core-image

I'm trying to set up a CIAdditionCompositing filter using the following code:

```
CIImage *imageOne = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"picOne"].CGImage];
CIImage *imageTwo = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"picTwo"].CGImage];

filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAdditionCompositing"];
[filter setDefaults];
[filter setValue:imageOne forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue:imageTwo forKey:kCIInputBackgroundImageKey];

CIImage *imageResult  = [filter outputImage];
CGImageRef imageRef = [context createCGImage:imageResult fromRect:imageResult.extent];
_imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

and am seeing the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[<__NSCFConstantString 0x2e2d60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key inputImage.'

on the line

```
[filter setValue:imageOne forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
```

What am I doing wrong in the setup of this Core Image filter?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could supply more information. For example, what line is throwing the exception?

Comment: exception - UnknownKey! kCIInputImageKey = @"inputImage"

Answer (score 1):

Vary strange, this method works...

```
filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAdditionCompositing" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, imageOne, kCIInputBackgroundImageKey, imageTwo, nil];
```

can anyone explain the difference?